# Replace the last character in a string

Tags: string, go

```
s=s[:len(s)-1] + "c"
```

I came across the need to solve this problem, and I was surprised to find out there is no direct `s[index] = "c"` way (I guess this means strings are immutable?).

Is the above the best way to replace just the last character in a string?

Comment: *"I guess this means strings are immutable?"* -- You guessed right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a function that works for UTF-8 encoded strings.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func replaceLastRune(s string, new rune) string {
    old, size := utf8.DecodeLastRuneInString(s)
    if old == utf8.RuneError && size <= 1 {
        return s
    }
    return s[:len(s)-size] + string(new)
}

func main() {
    s := "Hello WorlΔ"
    fmt.Println(s)
    s = replaceLastRune(s, 'd')
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/2LsSSS-5Y2l

```
Hello WorlΔ
Hello World
```

Answer (score -4):

Use regex:

```
regexp.MustCompile(".$").ReplaceAllString(s, "c")
```

---

See [live demo](https://go.dev/play/p/_RBpvUsoUeC)

```
s := "reli大"
s = regexp.MustCompile(".$").ReplaceAllString(s, "c")
println(s) // prints "relic"
```